# ¿How could I get all the text between two tags with RegExp, and then replacing the whole block with another text?

Tags: unix, sed, sh

I have a log file with several lines as an example.

One example from the log file could be:

```
-BEG DET
-SOME TEXT RANDOM REFERING TO REG DET
-SOME TEXT RANDOM REFERING TO REG DET
-SOME TEXT RANDOM REFERING TO REG DET
-END DET
```

The output needed should be:

```
BEG DET OMITTED
```

With that said, what I need would be to replace all that text inside the tags "-BEG DET" and "-END DET", without quotes, and the replace all the block, including the tags mentioned, with one unique line: BEG DET OMITTED.

As a note, the number of lines between the tags is variable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide `sample input` and `expected output` clearly and what you've tried so far.

Comment: REG or BEG? Please check your question.

Comment: Time for another tool? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26290

Comment: Mmmmm Perl for these things seems to be clearear and easier, I'll give it a try.

Comment: sed is for s/old/new, that is all. For any other text processing you should use awk. Leaping all the way to perl for this is like realizing your tree's too big to cut down with a hand saw and going straight for taking it down with TNT instead of using a chainsaw. What you're trying to do would be absolutely trivial in awk and would work on all standard UNIX systems with no need to install non-standard tools.

Comment: Is there anything else in the file? Any more text above or below these lines? Any other REG blocks?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat file
foo
-BEG DET
-SOME TEXT RANDOM REFERING TO REG DET
-SOME TEXT RANDOM REFERING TO REG DET
-SOME TEXT RANDOM REFERING TO REG DET
-END DET
bar

$ awk '/-BEG DET/{print $0, "OMITTED"; f=1} !f{print} /-END DET/{f=0}' file
foo
-BEG DET OMITTED
bar
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it with sed:

```
sed  -e '/^-BEG/!b' -e ':a' -e'N;/\n-END/!ba' -e 's/\n.*/ OMITTED/;s/-//' filename
```